# React HashRouter 4.2 header and footer on some routes

Tags: reactjs

How do I nest routes so I show a header and footer on some pages?

I have this code:

```
<HashRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
    <Route path="/rlogin" component={ReceiverLoginForm} />
    <Route path="/profile" component={Profile} />
    <Route path="/details" component={Details} />
  </Switch>
</HashRouter>
```

I also have a `<Header>` and `<Footer>` component that I want to display on all pages except the `Home` and `About` pages.

How do I do that?  I can't figure out how to nest routes or anything like that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I wound up doing it so I don't have repeated routes with lots of headers and footers:

```
render() {
    const headerFooterRoutes = ["/rlogin", "/profile", "/details"]
    return (
        <MuiThemeProvider>
            <Provider store={store}>
                <div id="wrapper">
                    <HashRouter>
                        <Switch>
                            {headerFooterRoutes.map(path =>
                                <Route path={path} component={Header}/>
                            )}
                        </Switch>
                    </HashRouter>
                    <HashRouter>
                        <Switch>
                            <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                            <Route path="/rlogin" component={LoginForm}/>
                            <Route path="/profile" component={Profile} />
                            <Route path="/details" component={Details} />
                        </Switch>
                    </HashRouter>
                    <HashRouter>
                        <Switch>
                            {headerFooterRoutes.map(path =>
                                <Route path={path} component={Footer}/>
                            )}
                        </Switch>
                    </HashRouter>
                </div>
            </Provider>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
}
```

Comment: make sure it doesn't cause problems to have multiple `HashRouter`s.

Answer (score 1):

Since your're using the `Switch` which prevents you from matching more than 1 route. you can just use `render` method of `Route` instead of `component`.

```
<HashRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
    <Route path="/rlogin" render={() => (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <ReceiverLoginForm />
        <Footer />
      </div>
    ) />
    {/* Do the same for the routes that you want the Header & Footer on */}
  </Switch>
</HashRouter>
```

Find more about [Route render method](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/Route-render-methods)

Comment: Thanks, this works but see my solution also which gets rid of having lots of routes with the header and footer repeated all over the place...